# Infinitive clauses in syntactic bracketing/trees

Tags: syntax, syntax-trees

I am a little confused on how the bracketing of a sentence like “millie forced me to play” would look like when also breaking down the tenses within the phrase. Thank you!

Comment: The second verb is an infinitive, and they don't have any tense. The first verb is past tense.